# Using as.Date to get previous n months

Tags: r, date

`as.Date()` has a useful function in that it can give you the last `n` days as, e.g.:

```
dt <- Sys.Date()-6
> dt
 [1] "2015-09-25"
```

Is there a way to tell it to give the last six months instead of the last six days?

I need something more precise than `6*30`, as it should be the last day of the month.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843439/problems-adding-a-month-to-x-using-posixlt-in-r-need-to-reset-value-using-as-d/14847439#14847439

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use just `Sys.Date` to do this but there are ways. The following will give you just the correct months but not the correct days (i.e. the last day of the month):

```
#Sys.Date will return 2015-10-01 today
dates <- seq( Sys.Date() - months(6), Sys.Date(), '1 month')
dates
[1] "2015-04-01" "2015-05-01" "2015-06-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-08-01" "2015-09-01" "2015-10-01"
```

However, I found [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/find-the-last-day-of-the-month/) very nice blog on R-bloggers which defines this function ( I slightly modified it to work with Dates) that returns the last day of the month:

```
eom <- function(date) {
  # date character string containing POSIXct date
  date.lt <- as.POSIXlt(dates) # add a month, then subtract a day:
  mon <- date.lt$mon + 2 
  year <- date.lt$year
  year <- year + as.integer(mon==13) # if month was December add a year
  mon[mon==13] <- 1
  iso = ISOdate(1900+year, mon, 1, hour=0, tz='')
  result = as.POSIXct(iso) - 86400 # subtract one day
  result + (as.POSIXlt(iso)$isdst - as.POSIXlt(result)$isdst)*3600
}
```

Now running:

```
> eom(dates)
[1] "2015-04-30 BST" "2015-05-31 BST" "2015-06-30 BST" "2015-07-31 BST" "2015-08-31 BST" "2015-09-30 BST" "2015-10-31 GMT"
```

Returns the correct results.

Comment: That is an awesome function!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
today = Sys.Date()
lastSixMonths = seq(today, length.out=6, by="-1 month")

print(lastSixMonths)
# [1] "2015-10-01" "2015-09-01" "2015-08-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-06-01"
# [6] "2015-05-01"
```